# Execute function after another function is triggered when selecting an item from a tableView

Tags: swift, func, completionhandler

When an item is selected within my tableView, I want the first func, **fetchChosenExerciseData**, to be executed before the second, **goToSegue**, is triggered. How can I implement this? I have had a look at completion blocks but to no avail.

A snippet of my code is below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    exerciseChosen = cell.textLabel!.text!
    duplicatesRemovedFromSetDataList.removeAll()
    fetchChosenExerciseData()
    goToSegue()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And it will be. What's the issue?

Comment: The functions are executed almost simultaneously, therefore the data has not be retrieved before the segue is triggered.

Comment: write the  goToSegue() function inside the fetchChosenExerciseData(). if they are in same class.

Comment: Or as you suggested, use a completion block as parameter of your `fetchChosenData()` function

Comment: They are not executed simultaneously. `fetchChosenExerciseData` will execute first,  then `goToSegue`. Now whether you are scheduling some asynchronous task inside  `fetchChosenExerciseData` is another matter. It would help if you posted the definition of `fetchChosenExerciseData` function

Answer (score 1):

Since `fetchChosenExerciseData` is  asynchronous you need this structure

```
func fetchChosenExerciseData(completion:@escaping()->()) {
    Api.load { 
        completion()
    }
}
```

---

Call

```
fetchChosenExerciseData { 
    goToSegue()
}
```

Comment: I now get an error within ** didSelectRowAt**, saying  "missing argument for parameter 'completion'". Is this where I insert `fetchChosenExerciseData { 
    goToSegue()
}`?  Apologies for the beginner questions

Comment: Code within **didSelectRowAt** has not changed but the function has.
`func fetchChosenExerciseData(completion:@escaping()->()){
  //code
  completion()`

Answer (score 0):

this is simply achievable use a completion handler:

```
func fetchChosenExerciseData(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
     // do what you need
     completion()
}
```

in your `didSelectRowAt` you can insert your second function

```
fetchChosenExerciseData {
    // goToSegue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your function `fetchChosenExerciseData`has some asynchoronous part or some code that is being executed on different Queue.

For conditions like this you should use completion block.
So you would have to declare the `fetchChosenExerciseData' like this

```
func fetchChosenExerciseData (completion (()->()))
{
// Enter your code 
completion()
}
```

I have read you have done this solution, but i believe there must be some mistake in that

Answer (score 0):

First of all add completion block to your method `fetchChosenExerciseData` like

```
func fetchChosenExerciseData(finished: () -> Void) {
     print("Doing something whatever you want!")
     finished()
}
```

and then call your function `goToSegue` from completion block of your first method like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    exerciseChosen = cell.textLabel!.text!
    duplicatesRemovedFromSetDataList.removeAll()
    fetchChosenExerciseData{
    goToSegue()
   }
}
```

Hope this help!